# Identify origin in generator=links

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

The following call scans two pages on en.wikipedia.org and returns pages which are linked from those:

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&formatversion=2&errorformat=plaintext&action=query&generator=links&gplnamespace=%2A&gpllimit=max&titles=Mannequin%7CResuscitation

But I am unable to identify which links occur on which page. For example, the link to `nuclear tests` exists on the `Mannequin` page, but this is not indicated in the output of the above. I would like to have that information in the output.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most generators don't provide any kind of information about the generated page. (See https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T263841 for a somewhat related discussion.) You'd have to turn it into a non-generator query. In your specific example you don't actually take advantage of it being a generator, so this is easy to do:
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&formatversion=2&errorformat=plaintext&action=query&prop=links&plnamespace=%2A&pllimit=max&titles=Mannequin%7CResuscitation
In other cases, not using a generator might mean you need to make some extra queries.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. It will take a while for me to go through that phab thread. A quick follow-up: What is the use case for the links prop as a generator? Drawing on your comment that my example does not actually make use of it.

Comment: Generators feed into other API modules; they basically replace the `titles` parameter. Try adding something like `prop=info` to your query: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=jsonfm&formatversion=2&errorformat=plaintext&action=query&generator=links&gplnamespace=%2A&gpllimit=max&titles=Mannequin%7CResuscitation&prop=info or `prop=revisions`: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=jsonfm&formatversion=2&errorformat=plaintext&action=query&generator=links&gplnamespace=%2A&gpllimit=max&titles=Mannequin%7CResuscitation&prop=revisions

Comment: Finally I got to reading that phab thread. Very useful, thank you! I am not clear however on how exactly this will affect `gen=links`. Currently, it returns the _linked_ page's `pageid` as part of the result. If the RFC is implemented, what would one do to obtain the _originating_ pageid? It is unclear to me how the RFC solves this problem (or if it is even trying to).

Comment: Would it make sense for me to ask in the phab thread? Don't want to break the etiquette by intruding...

Comment: You are welcome to, use cases are always helpful in an RfC. I do intend to follow up there, though - I agree the page id has been a bit of a bind spot in that discussion.

Comment: I [looked into it](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T271048) a bit more, it seems like a fair bit of work, so unless a more compelling use case is found or someone volunteers to do it, I doubt it will be changed.